# Хранение имени и адреса

Tags: сессия, php, cookie

Добрый день. У меня есть блог. Я пытаюсь улучшить добавление комментариев, сделав запоминание имени и эл. адреса (т.е. пользователю один раз придется вводить свое имя и адрес, дальше оно будет заполняться автоматически). Как лучше хранить его: в cookie или в session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторюсь,

- сессии - на сервере;
- куки - на
     клиенте.

Исходя из безопасности, пользовательские данные необходимо хранить в сессиях (в этом случаем в куках будет храниться хэш-индификатор сессии).

В куках же, должны храниться данные, которые не являются конфиденциальными и требуют длительного хранения, к примеру, некая статистика для маркетинговых исследований, а также, индикаторы различных инструментов на сайте, для их визуализации (как пример: скрыть данную плашку навсегда). Так или иначе, все те данные, которые в БД хранить нецелесообразно.

Для кук и сессий можно установить время их жизни. Правда, иногда время жизни сессий может быть ограничено хостингом (free-/эконом-хостинги)

Comment: если я верно понял автора, то ему нужны куки т.к. данные будут подставлятся в поля ввода, которые пользователь и так вводит сам!(система коментариев для "гостей").

Comment: @ToRcH565 Возможно. Зависит от корректности заданного вопроса.
Если просто автозаполнение полей, то с этим легко справляется браузер.

Comment: Не любой браузер, и от настроек зависит) + необходимо начало слов печатать... а таким способом при входе на страницу данные уже будут введены, либо будет создаватся илюзия "залогинености", зависит от того что хочет автор :)

Comment: @ToRcH565 Ну разве что только логин, ибо пароль в явном виде нигде нельзя хранить, тем более в куках.

Answer (score 0):

куки - хранятся у пользователя и каждый раз передаются на сервер(при каждом запросе).
Сессия - хранится на сервере и живет ограниченное время,(обычно 30 мин) также в куки пишется айди сессии.

В вашем случае думаю куки будут лучше, и именно то что нужно. Т.к. время жизни - установленное вами или до удаления их пользователем, + обьем информации не большой чтобы экономить трафик...

Comment: Upd отсчет времени хранения куков ведется с момента установки(лучше обновлять при каждом посещении страницы)
Отсчет времени хранения сессий - с момента последнего вызова.